# Sorting lat long for KML file using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, kml

I was wondering if anyone could help me please.

I am trying to put some latlong into a KML file for Google Earth to use. But from my testing, it seems that the KML file doesn't like really long latlongs and gives me "######" in the kml if its too long.

I have been trying to create some code so if a latlong string is greater than 230 characters long, it will cut it into segments so that each line will have  smaller than 230 characters.

The code needs to cut the latlong and paste each new part onto a new row in a worksheet. Each line of the latlong must finish with ",0" and each line must start with a new lat long so "-1.39,55.292,0 -1.32 ..... etc)

I tried the following:

LatLong = "-1.39665,55.92563,0 -2.39654,52.92552,0 -3.39626,51.92541,0 -3.39617,55.92533,0 -3.39621,41.92526,0 -3.39649,51.92525,0 -3.39668,55.92529,0 -1.39684,23.92537,0 -3.39686,50.92549,0 -3.39688,41.9256,0 -1.39684,23.92537,0 -3.39686,50.92549,0 -3.39688,41.9256,0 -1.39684,23.92537,0 -3.39686,50.92549,0 -3.39688,41.9256,0"

```
    Dim Revserse As String
    Dim length2 As String
    length2 = Len(LatLong)
    Dim point As Integer
    Dim NewLatLong As String

If Len(LatLong) < 230 Then
    ActiveCell.Value = LatLong
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Else

    NewLatLong = Left(LatLong, 230)
    Revserse = StrReverse(NewLatLong)
    For i = 1 To Len(Revserse)
        If Mid(Revserse, i, 2) = "0," Then
            point = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    point = 230 - point

First_new_latlong = Left(LatLong, (point + 1))

Second_new_latlong= Right(LatLong, (length2 - (point + 1)))
MsgBox newlatlong1

MsgBox newlatlong2
End if
```

However, my code above doesn't check if the new chopped portion of the latlong is again longer than 230 characters. But I can't figure it out. I think there needs to be a for loop that constantly checks if the new latlong is greater than 230 but because of the constrains, i.e. must end with ",0" and the new line must start with a new latlong "-1.29,55.11,0..." it gets tricky.

I wonder if anyone can help?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why do you need to go all the way to (nearly) 230 characters before starting the next line?  Can't you just append a `vbCrLf` after **every** coordinate (lat/long/alt) you write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see of the KML specification, there should be no need to have more than one coordinate triplet on a single line.  (Undoubtedly you **can** do so, but you don't **need** to do so.)

Therefore you should be able to just insert a CR/LF between each triplet instead of a space:

```
Dim latlong As String
latlong = "-1.39665,55.92563,0 -2.39654,52.92552,0 -3.39626,51.92541,0 -3.39617,55.92533,0 -3.39621,41.92526,0 -3.39649,51.92525,0 -3.39668,55.92529,0 -1.39684,23.92537,0 -3.39686,50.92549,0 -3.39688,41.9256,0 -1.39684,23.92537,0 -3.39686,50.92549,0 -3.39688,41.9256,0 -1.39684,23.92537,0 -3.39686,50.92549,0 -3.39688,41.9256,0"

latlong = Replace(latlong, " ", vbCrLf)

MsgBox latlong
```

The string generated from that code should then be able to be inserted into the KML file.

Comment: Thanks YowE3k for the help!